# Faster way to get selection bounding boxes

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to get the bounding box coordinates of certain groups of faces. I am running this in a frame update so I'm trying to squeeze out as much performance as possible. I use the result of the bounding box coordinates to place labels in the 3d space, but this part of the code takes too long to execute with vertex counts higher than 100.000. Is there a way to optimize the first part of this code?

```
bmfaces = bm.faces
tempfaces = bmfaces
fm = bmfaces.layers.face_map.verify()
...
for map_idx, map in enumerate(obj.face_maps):

   selection = []

   for f in filter(lambda f: f[fm] == map_idx ,tempfaces):
       selection.extend(f.calc_center_median())

   if not selection:
       continue

   selection = np.array(selection)
   selection = selection = np.reshape(selection,(int(len(selection)/3),3))

   min_coords = [selection[:,i].min() for i in range(3)]
   max_coords = [selection[:,i].max() for i in range(3)]
```

This is the approach I'm using at the moment. I tried listing all vertices from the faces and getting their coordinates, but calc_center_median() proved faster. Is there any way to get vertex coordinates from a selection faster? Foreach_get would be ideal but I'm not sure how to filter the result of that with the face map index. My numpy knowledge is very basic so maybe I'm missing something there as well.

Comment: Can you comment out the two lines, *if f in set(tempfaces): tempfaces.remove(f)*?